# Why would a pilot want to land with less than full flaps?

Tags: landing, flaps, flight-simulator

So for example if I am flying the Boeing 737-800, the FMC gives me three flap settings and approach speeds.

Why would a pilot want to fly with anything less than full flaps where possible?

Comment: If flying a GA aircraft and you encounter icing, the recommended practice is to land without extending the flaps unless you are sure the wing surfaces are clear of ice.

Comment: If you are below the glide-slope during short-final, you landing speed has to be higher than usual, or else you'll stall inches above ground - it might end up being fatal!

Answer (score 14):

Less flaps gives a faster approach speed. In some scenarios, a faster approach speed is better than a slow one, for example:

- Strong crosswind
- Possible wind shear
- One-engine failure

A higher approach speed provides a better stall margin and higher control authority in challenging situations. For example, the Boeing 737 QRH calls for a flaps 15 landing in "One Engine Inoperative" and "Stabilizer Trim Inoperative" scenarios.

In the crosswind scenario, let's assume your approach speed is 100 knots, and the crosswind is 20 knots. The crosswind is therefore 1/5 of the approach speed, and you need a larger crab angle to keep the airplane aligned with the runway. If you increase your approach speed to 120 knots, then the crosswind is only 1/6 of the approach speed, and the crab angle is smaller, making landing easier.

Comment: Besides, it's advisable to use little or no flaps when landing in turbulent conditions, since a higher speed ensures a more uniform lift when flying in turbulent air...

Comment: @xxavier, what is your source for that?

Comment: @acpilot not sure about the aerodynamics part, but it is stated at least in the 737 FCTM: `Flap extension in an area of known turbulence should be delayed as long as possible because the airplane can withstand higher gust loads with the flaps up.`

Comment: @kevin: This is valid for approach, but not landing.

Comment: Higher speed with the same flap setting does certainly provide more margin from stall. However, since less flaps mean higher stall speed, is it really true with less flaps?

Comment: @Jan Hudec   But you are flying slower whith lowered flaps, and when flying at a small airspeed an in turbulent conditions, it may happen that you get a gust from behind, a strong gust, and the lift of one wing, or both, may thus fall to zero for a small, but critical span of time. Once, I crashed because of that. It wasn't a stall, but a sudden loss of altitude, while on final...

Comment: @xxavier, but is the difference in flight speed bigger than the difference in stall speeds between the configuration? I suppose it might be (and if you are using the standard rule that $V_{ref} = 1.3 V_s$, it will be, slightly), but using less flaps does not imply it. And it seems to me it would be better to just increase $V_{ref}$, but still deploy full flaps as then the speed difference would be even bigger. Why isn't it?

Comment: @Jan Hudec Well, I'm not talking about stall, that is a different thing. In the case of an (strong enough) 'gust from behind' the flow may simply disappear, as the magnitude of the relative wind 'seen' by the wing 'sees' drops to zero for a short time. Of course, the way to reduce this danger is to fly the final at a higher speed, and that can be done, within limits, with or without flaps, but it's easier without flaps...

Comment: @xxavier, the gust from behind will get you in trouble if it reduces your speed below stall (no need for all the way down to zero; that would be very strong gust). So it still makes sense to have the flaps out to reduce the stall speed (and keep the extra speed for gusts).

Comment: @Jan Hudec  No, a 'gust from behind' does not cause an stall, because the stall takes place only when the angle of attack gets over a critical value and the flow detaches from the wind. The 'gust from behind' lowers the relative airspeed, and thus lowers the lift, but does not affect the AoA, so there is no flow detachment at all, no stall...

Comment: @xxavier: Does the exact terminology matter more than the fact that in either case the airplane is likely to impact the ground in an uncontrolled fashion?

Comment: folks: continue in chat is recommended.

Comment: @xxavier, indirectly it does, because pilot will try to correct the change in flight path. But I see the total speed does make a difference then, because at higher speed, the change in flight path will be smaller.

Comment: @jamesqf, this is about correct understanding of the physics. We were *not* talking about the same thing in different terms. Exact terminology matters as far as necessary to understand it—in physics you usually do have to be precise.

Comment: @Jan Hudec  Yes, if the pilot pulls the stick under those conditions, the wing will stall. But a gust is a very short-lived event, and there's no time for a reaction for the pilot...

Comment: @Jan Hudec: It's about physics?  My mistake: I thought it was about how to land your airplane without hitting the ground hard enough to cause major damage.

Comment: @jamesqf, the question is about how to land the plane, but the discussion is about the physics explaining why it has to be done in that particular way.

Answer (score 4):

In strong crosswind-conditions you want to consider not using full flaps to give the wind less attack area. So you have a slightly higher approach and landing speed, but you aren't blown as much to the side as you would be with full flaps.

In a Cessna 172, for example, this is normal practice.

Comment: Well, if you're landing in a crosswind of X m/s, you'll be 'blown' sideways at exactly X m/s, no matter the landing speed you have... Unless you crab, of course, in which case you won't be blown sideways at all. The crab angle with flaps will be higher, but that's the only difference. And when you align with the runway, at the last moment, you'll be blown sideways at X m/s, irrespective of your speed at that moment...

Comment: @xxavier No, you won't be *instantly* be blown sideways at X m/s "at the last moment", because the plane has mass, and therefore takes time to *accelerate* sideways up to X m/s.

Comment: @alephzero. Yes, it takes precisely that small time, that is the same at any landing speed...

Answer (score 0):

In a Cessna 150 for example, you want to be on the downwind going 70-75 knots, 65-70 on base, and 55-65 on final, depending on wind gusts. A pilot in a small plane might tend to put in 10° of flaps on the downwind, 10° on base, and adjustments or anything extra on final to allow them to get their speed to where they need it. It is nice to be in the middle where you can add or remove some if necessary (assuming you're not too close to the ground).